# The image drawn in pygame does not match the location it is given

Tags: python, image, pygame, draw, blit

Hello everyone I am learning the basics of pygame.
I recently ran into a problem;
I decided to load an image and gave it a random location well within the pygame window.But the problem was that sometimes it just wont appear in the window. So I drew a black pointer at the place where the image was to be loaded. Then I found out that the black pointer doesnot coincide with the image and hence the image is not appearing in the location I want it to be in.
So I want help solving this problem.
Thank you in advance.
Code:

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

#Pygame starters
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Blob runner")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
targetpng = pygame.image.load("target.png")
#Quit checker
crashed = False
#COLOURS
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)


def draw_environment(x,y):    
    game_display.fill(white)
    #Image
    game_display.blit(targetpng,(x, y)) 
    #Black pointer
    pygame.draw.circle(game_display, black, (x, y), 5 )
    pygame.display.update()

x, y = random.randrange(0,display_width), random.randrange(0,display_height)

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        # print(event)

    draw_environment(x,y)
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Image:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has a size. it may happen that the image is out of the window at the right or at the bottom. The origin of the [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) puts the the **top left** corner of the image to the specified position.

If you wan that the image is centered at *(x, y)*, the you have to get a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) with the size of the image (`get_rect`) and set the center of the rectangle to the specified position (keyword argument). Use the rectangle to specify the position for the `blit` operation.

```py
img_rect = targetpng.get_rect(center = (x, y))
game_display.blit(targetpng, img_rect)
```

Th image has a size, thus the random position for the image has to be in range *[image_size/2, window_sizw - image_size/2]*.
The width and height of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) can be get by `get_width()`/`get_height()` or `get_size()`. For instance:

```py
img_size = targetpng.get_size()
x = random.randrange(img_size[0]//2, display_width  - img_size[0]//2)
y = random.randrange(img_size[1]//2, display_height - img_size[1]//2)
```

Comment: Everything you said was correct. But there was a slight unwise move made by me which I can assume that every beginner might make, so I am going to address that in my answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I now understand what went wrong with the insight provided by @Rabbid76.

The thing is I drew the picture in paint and then opened the file in gimp to convert whites in the image to alpha(the checkerboard-like background) . But the problem occurred when I did  not clear of the unwanted alpha as I thought the computer will not recognise the alpha but as matter of fact it does.

So when I loaded the image, the corner of the image is not of the actual "target spot" but of the entire image, so the corner will be on the alpha. The black dot was pointing at the corner of the image all along and the image sometimes did not appear because the corner was too close to the border so the image would trespass to the un-displayed portion of the window.

So the fix is to clear of the alpha or the white background to minimum and only then convert it into alpha. Then do as @Rabbid76 says :D.